# How do I implement convolution in KDB?

Tags: kdb

I'm trying to convolve a small vector (kernel) across a longer series.

The simplest possible kernel is `(-1 1)`, which is the equivalent of the `diff` operator.

My failed attempt is:

```
{sum (x;y)*(-1;1)} scan til 10

0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5
```

This doesn't work, as it supplies the previous evaluation as the right component of the binary fn. What I should be doing is evaluating the function on each pair and storing the result. The result I'm looking for is:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

What I can't figure out is an elegant KDB way of doing this calculation.

Is there an elegant way to do this in KDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the each prior iterator to do this - https://code.kx.com/q/ref/maps/#each-prior

```
q)-':[til 10]
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: Although this is technically the right answer, it's limited to kernels of size 2. Any idea how I might drag a larger kernel across a long vector?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
q)1_sum(1;-1)*1 prev\til 10
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Can you provide more examples?